# How do you draw in multiple colors with grease pencil?

Tags: grease-pencil

Im trying to draw in color, but all my strokes come out the same grey color, no matter if I use material or vertex color.

[image: Drawing is grey]

I have also seen related questions or tutorials where the way they change the color is by either changing the material of a stroke manually or using the tint tool (not that I got those to work either) and what I want is for the stroke to act like strokes in a drawing program, being drawn in the color selected directly and all.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure that you are in *material preview shading* or *rendered shading* (unfortunately you cut the top of the viewport on the image on the question, don't do that).

[image]

Color will not appear in solid view.

[image]

---

For Material.

Set the material for the stroke and fill in the material properties window.

[image]

---

For vertex color

Set the color directly either on the top color selector on the screen.

[image]

Or use the tool options in the properties window.

[image]